# Algorithm behind the shadow/highlight filter in photoshop

Tags: algorithm, photoshop, highlight, shadow

I am very interested in the shadow/highlight filter in photoshop. Does anybody has any ideas about the algorithm behind the shadow/highlight filter?

Comment: I would guess it uses the `Radius` to determine the locality or size of the area it is applying to. In the case of shadows, it then boosts the brightness by the `Amount`. The `Tonal Range` then specified how far away - in brightness terms - pixels may be before they are no longer considered candidates for brightening. The `Highlights` is then the converse.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little 10-step wedge of various shades of black-white and went through the various values of Shadow in the Shadow and Highlight settings for you and animated the movie so you can see how the histogram is moving...

[image]

You can see as the `Amount` increases, the more the second histogram bar moves to the right. As the `Tone` increases, so more and more different shadow tones are affected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have found an alternative solution for the shadow/highlight filter.

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: Curious to see what solution you found as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not accurate but imitates well.

```
lumR = 0.299;
lumG = 0.587;
lumB = 0.114;

// we have to find luminance of the pixel
// here 0.0 <= source.r/source.g/source.b <= 1.0 
// and 0.0 <= luminance <= 1.0

luminance = sqrt( lumR*pow(source.r,2.0) + lumG*pow(source.g,2.0) + lumB*pow(source.b,2.0));



// here highlights and and shadows are our desired filter amounts
// highlights/shadows should be >= -1.0 and <= +1.0
// highlights = shadows = 0.0 by default
// you can change 0.05 and 8.0 according to your needs but okay for me

h = highlights * 0.05 * ( pow(8.0, luminance) - 1.0 );
s = shadows * 0.05 * ( pow(8.0, 1.0 - luminance) - 1.0 );

output.r = source.r + h + s;
output.g = source.g + h + s;
output.b = source.b + h + s;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new layer blending mode "soft light" with the 50% gray background.
2. Select the "brush" with pressing a 4%.
3. Press the "D"
   Black - shadow. White - highlight. To quickly change the second color - press the "X"

I hope this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for your valueable instructions.  I have found an alternative solution for the shadow/highlight filter.